# What does this gdb warning mean? I get it when I try to dump backtrace for a core file

Tags: debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

I saw this nifty one liner for gdb to dump out backtrace for all threads after a core dump. So I tried a quick:

```
int main() {int* x = new int[5]; for(int i = 0; true; ++i) x[i] = i; }
```

to get a core dump and then ran this:

```
gdb --batch --quiet -ex "thread apply all bt full" -ex "quit" a.out core.box-name.a.out.27459.8515.11
```

And I get the output:

```
[New LWP 27459]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff9e503000
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004005ca in main () at <stdin>:6
6       <stdin>: No such file or directory.

Thread 1 (LWP 27459):
#0  0x00000000004005ca in main () at <stdin>:6
        i = 33788
        x = 0x1a460010
```

I see a backtrace which is nice, but am wondering what the two warnings I also see are about?

Comment: what's your gcc version, compile command and os version?

Answer (score 1):

Seems from this link, it was a bug in gdb and has been fixed in the recent releases.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=248898